# Do ambident nucleophiles form functional isomers?

Tags: isomers, nucleophilicity

I came across **cyanide and isocyanide** in an example for functional isomerism. As they are also ambident nuclephiles, I wanted to know if other ambident nucleophiles would also exhibit functional isomerism.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ambident nucleophiles show functional isomerism. Two examples are:

1. Cyanide ($\ce{CN}$) and isocyanide ($\ce{NC}$)
2. Nitrite ($\ce{ONO}$) and Nitro ($\ce{NO2}$)

Comment: Nitpick: Cyanide is already mentioned in OP's question. Here is a different example: "thiocyanate $\ce{-SCN}$".